# Aggregation is very slow

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with a structure similar to this.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d7cd63dc2c91e740afcdb"),
    "dateJoined": ISODate("2014-12-28T16:37:17.984Z"),
    "activatedMonth": 5,
    "enrollments" : [
        { "month":-10, "enrolled":'00'},
        { "month":-9, "enrolled":'00'},
        { "month":-8, "enrolled":'01'},
        //other months
        { "month":8, "enrolled":'11'},
        { "month":9, "enrolled":'11'},
        { "month":10, "enrolled":'00'}
    ]
}
```

month in enrollments sub document is a relative month from dateJoined.

**activatedMonth is a month of activation relative to dateJoined. So, this will be different for each document.**

I am using Mongodb aggregation framework to process queries like "Find all documents that are enrolled from 10 months before <del>dateJoined</del> activating to 25 months after <del>dateJoined</del> activating".

"enrolled" values 01, 10, 11 are considered enrolled and 00 is considered not enrolled. For a document to be considered to to be enrolled, it should be enrolled for every month in the range.

I am applying all the filters that I can apply in the match stage but this can be empty in most cases. In projection phase I am trying to find out the all the document with at least one not-enrolled month. if the size is zero, then the document is enrolled.

Below is the query that I am using. It takes 3 to 4 seconds to finish. It is more or less same time with or with out the group phase. My data is relatively smaller in size ( 0.9GB) and total number of documents are 41K and sub document count is approx. 13 million.

I need to reduce the processing time. I tried creating an index on enrollments.month and enrollment.enrolled and is of no use and I think it is because of the fact that project stage cant use indexes. Am I right?

Are there are any other things that I can do to the query or the collection structure to improve performance?

```
let startMonth = -10;
let endMonth = 25;

mongoose.connection.db.collection("collection").aggregate([
  {
    $match: filters
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      enrollments: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$enrollment",
            as: "enrollment",
            cond: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $gte: [
                    '$$enrollment.month',
                    {
                       $add: [
                         startMonth,
                         "$activatedMonth"
                       ]
                     }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $lte: [
                    '$$enrollment.month',
                    {
                       $add: [
                         startMonth,
                         "$activatedMonth"
                       ]
                     }

                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    '$$enrollment.enroll',
                    '00'
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      enrollments: {
        $eq: 0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      enrolled: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
]).toArray(function(err,
result){
  //some calculations
}
});
```

Also, I definitely need the group stage as I will group the counts based on different field. I have omitted this for simplicity.

Edit:

I have missed a key details in the initial post. Updated the question with the actual use case why I need projection with a calculation.

**Edit 2: 
I converted this to just a count query to see how it performs (based on comments to this question by Niel Lunn.**

My query:

```
mongoose.connection.db.collection("collection")
  .find({ 
      "enrollment": { 
          "$not": { 
             "$elemMatch": { "month": { "$gte": startMonth, "$lte": endMonth }, "enrolled": "00" } 
           } 
       } 
   })
   .count(function(e,count){
     console.log(count);
 });
```

This query is taking 1.6 seconds. I tried with following indexes separately:

```
   1. { 'enrollment.month':1 }
   2. { 'enrollment.month':1 }, { 'enrollment.enrolled':1 } -- two seperate indexes
   3. { 'enrollment.month':1, 'enrollment.enrolled':1}  - just one index on both fields.
```

Winning query plan is not using keys in any of these cases, it does a COLLSCAN always. What am I missing here?

Comment: You don't need an aggregation for this. You don't state what `filters` is actually doing, so that's a problem. However the core logic of *"Does not match these conditions in ANY array element"* is simply `.find({ "enrollment": { "$not": { "$elemMatch": { "month": { "$gte": startMonth, "$lte": endMonth }, "enrolled": "00" } } } }).count()`. Then it's really all about "indexes", so make sure you have them. Forcing a calculation is slow, and you don't need to do that.

Comment: @NeilLunn I am so sorry, I just realized that I missed some key details in order to make the question as simple as possible. I have updated my question.

Comment: The only "key detail" I see missing is "what are the query conditions in `filters`"? This is not an aggregation, and is a simple query to "count" the results returned. Just show the query conditions contained in `filter`, so you can actually try yourself and realize how much faster this is.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, "filters" can be empty or filter on other fields I have in the collection. I am not sure how i can use count if I need to calculate when the "month" is relative to one field and query is on another field. I need to calculate the difference for each document. in SQL it is like WHERE t.FullName = t.FirstName + t.LastName. Also your query about just returns all the documents not filtering anything.

Comment: Or are you really referring to this [Using a Dynamic Value in Aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46697878/2313887)? If you' actual conditions depend on data in the document, then there is not much you can do about that. The database has no choice other than to run the calculation over every document in order to do the comparison. Which I believe I told you when I answered that for you. If you want more speed, you "need a bigger boat". Or restructure the data so the conditions don't need to refer back to the data present in the document.

Comment: Yes. I have updated my question after your first comment. I added a field called activatedMonth.

Comment: @NeilLunn I changed my query to check just the count as you suggested to check the performance and see that even with indexes count itself is very slow. Can you check my Edit 2 in the question.