# MongoDB query is slow and not using Indexes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with structure like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d7cd63dc2c91e740afcdb"),
    "enrollment" : [
        { "month":-10, "enroll":'00'},
        { "month":-9, "enroll":'00'},
        { "month":-8, "enroll":'01'},
        //other months
        { "month":8, "enroll":'11'},
        { "month":9, "enroll":'11'},
        { "month":10, "enroll":'00'}
    ]
}
```

I am trying to run the following query:

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({ 
          "enrollment": { 
              "$not": { 
                 "$elemMatch": { "month": { "$gte": -2, "$lte": 9 }, "enroll": "00" } 
               } 
           } 
       }).count()
```

This query is taking 1.6 to 1.9 seconds. I need to get this down as low as possible, to milli seconds if that is possible.

I tried creating multi key index on month and enrolled fields. I tried various combinations but the query is not using any indexes.

I tried all these combinations:

```
1. { 'enrollment.month':1 }
2. { 'enrollment.month':1 }, { 'enrollment.enroll':1 } -- two seperate indexes
3. { 'enrollment.month':1, 'enrollment.enroll':1} 
4. { 'enrollment.enroll':1, 'enrollment.month':1}
```

Parsed Query:

[image]

Query Plan:

[image]

Any suggestions to improve the performance are highly appreciated.

I am fairly confident that the hardware is not an issues but open for any suggestions.

My data size is not huge. Its just under 1GB. Total number of documents are 41K and sub document count is approx. 13 million

Note: I have posted couple of questions on this in last few days, but with this i am trying to narrow down the area. Please do not take this as a duplicate of my earlier questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to inverse the query:

```
   db.getCollection('collection').find({ 
      "enrollment": { 
         "$elemMatch": { 
             "month": { "$lt": -2, "$gt": 9 }, 
             "enroll": {$ne: "00"} 
         } 
      } 
   }).count()
```

Comment: thank you. I can reverse the $lte and $gte but cannot move $ne inside. Please see this for the reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47085667/aggregation-is-very-slow . changing $lte and $gte did not made any difference

Comment: @user3731783 please read the rules. All information should be included in the question itself. When you update the question, please also  replace images with json code.